# Shutdown jupyter kernel

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am sharing my notebooks with colleagues by exposing the jupyter door on our internal network.
When they leave the notebook, a lot of kernels keep running.

I am looking for a way for automatically shutdown a jupyter-notebook kernel when exiting.
Does anyone know if it is possible?

Comment: explore this https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/pull/2215